# $\iiint_V \frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}} \,du\,dv\,dw$ on $V = \{(x,y,z): x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} \leq 1, 0.5 \leq z\}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

i used the spherical coordinates of a ball, so

$x = r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta),y = r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta), z = \cos(\phi)$

And my det(Jacobian) = $r^{2}\sin({\phi})$

now my boundries of $r$ are $0$->$1$ and $\theta = $$0$->$2\pi$ and $\phi = $$0$->$\frac{\pi}{3}$

if i fill this in i get $$\iiint_B \sin({\phi}) \,dr\,d\phi\,d\theta$$. With B are the boundries of $(r,\phi,\theta)$. can someone help me figuring out what i did wrong because the answer of this integral is not right??

Comment: I assume $du$, $dv$ and $dw$ are supposed to be $dr$, $d\phi$ and $d\theta$? And what is your $V$? The set you write doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Your integration limits give you the volume of the spherical cone. Your lower limit for $r$ must depend on the value of $\phi$.

Comment: In shperical coordinates, you have z = rcos(phi), thus when the limits of z >= .5, it is not cos(phi)>=.5 but rcos(phi) >=.5.  Will  it change the limit for phi and r as Daniel has pointed out?

Comment: @EuYu sorry about that, i changed it right away

Comment: @DanielFischer of course, i see what i did wrong thanks!

Comment: @KeesTil: in $V$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=??????$ or $x^2+y^2+z^2\le ??????$

Comment: @B.S. i'm sorry for al these errors, its smaller/equal 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the standard names $\phi$ for the azimuthal and $\theta$ for the
polar angle, the $r$-factors of the integrand and of the Jacobian cancel, and we may immediately integrate over $\phi$:
$$ \int \frac{1}{r^2} r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi
=2\pi \int \sin\theta dr d\theta
.
$$
The limits for the spherical cap are $$1/2 \le \cos\theta \le 1$$ and
$$ 1/(2 \cos \theta) \le r \le 1.$$
So integrating over $r$ yields
$$
2\pi\int_{1/2\le \cos\theta \le 1} \sin\theta d\theta [1-1/(2\cos\theta)].
$$
We substitute $\cos\theta = z$, $dz = -\sin\theta d\theta$, limits $1/2\le z\le 1$,
$$
\ldots
= -2\pi\int_1^{1/2} \frac{dz}{1-1/(2z)} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\ln 2) \approx 0.1534.
$$